# Operation with division resulting in error execution because of SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception

Tags: c, floating-point, sigfpe

I have wrote an algorithm for MCU that executes the expression of two paralel Resistances before doing more calculations with the division result. When debugging the values had no sense; they were too much big and float var did not update their initial value.

So I went to https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and I tried a part of my algorithm there. When execute the code it launches a non normally exiting with the arithmetic exception at line:

```
a = 1/(1/10 + 1/b) + 0.15;
```

First I was working with float but I have thought that exception could be caused by an overflow, hence I did the variable storage bigger using double, but the same exception appears. 
Then I tried doing the same but saying:

```
a = (1/10 + 1/b) + 0.15;
```

and the execution worked!

So, I have seen the '1' operator was the cause. But I don't understand exactly why and how to fix it (without using math.h).

The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float a = 0.0;
int b = 100;

int main()
{
    a = 1/(1/10 + 1/b) + 0.15;//Req 
    b = a; //get int part
    a *= 10;//fractionary part converted to dec
    if ((a - b*10)>5) b++;

    printf("float: %f , int: %i",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get (debugging):

- a = 1/(1/10 + 1/100) = 9.09

which I think is not a big value to fit in a float or a double var. Instead of this I get the exception.

How to work with floats/doubles and int values to avoid exceptions when 1/(something smaller)?

Answer (score 3):

Both `1/10` and `1/b` are ***integer*** expressions, which both result in the integer `0`.

So you have a plain division by zero error.

Solve it by using e.g. `1.0f` as the dividend, like `1.0f / (0.1f + 1.0f / b) + 0.15f`.

Comment: You have reason doing #include <stdio.h>


double a = 0.0;
int b = 100;

     int main()
    {
          a = 1.0/(1.0/10.0 + 1/(float)b) + 0.15;
          b = a;
          a *= 10;
          if ((a - b*10)>5) b++;
    
          printf("float: %f , int: %i",a,b);

          return 0;
    } is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 a = 1/(1/10 + 1/b) + 0.15;//Req
```

is doing integer division in the first part, since `1` and `10` are both of type `int`. You meant:

```
a = 1.f / (0.1f + 1.f / b) + 0.15f;
```

especially for embedded targets, it can be quite important to make sure your literals are `float`s and not `double`s, as the support can be different.